# Atomic increment of a non auto_increment column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, atomic

I have a table with two columns. One is auto_increment say columnA whereas other is a non auto_increment say columnB. I want to perform two types of insert operations in columnB:

1. Insert a constant number (for deliberate duplication)
2. Insert max(columnB) + 1 (this must not cause any duplication)

Operation 1 is simple but in operation 2 there can be duplication as operation is not completely atomic. I plan to use the following SQL:

insert table (columnB) select max(columnB)+1 from table

If several users hit the above SQL at exactly same time, it will cause duplication. I want to know how to make the statement completely atomic.

One thing more, if you suggest table locking is there anyway that there is a delayed insert instead of return of error due to table being locked?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a trigger that auto-increments your column B if needed.